# How to iterate through multiple arrays using one loop?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I have multiple arrays(currently 2) of the same type and I need to perform similar operations on these arrays.

```
Custom[] array1 = new Custom[10];
Custom[] array2 = new Custom[20];

// Assign values to array1 and array2

foreach(var v in array1)
{
// Do some operations
}

foreach(var v in array2)
{
// Do some operations
}
```

In both `foreach loops`, I am doing similar operations to the objects in the array.
These operations do modify some properties of the objects in arrays based on conditions.

Is there any way I can merge the `foreach loops`?
I want to maintain both the arrays as they are at the end of the process, so cannot copy one array to another or something like that. I also would like to avoid creating a new array that contains both arrays merged (I think it might cause an issue with space as Custom here can be Value types or Reference types).

One solution to this I found is having a separate function that contains the `foreach loop` and then calling the function for multiple arrays.

```
private void DoOperations(Custom[] array)
{
    foreach(var v in array)
    {
    // Do some operations
    }
}

// In main
DoOperations(array1);
DoOperations(array2);
```

I just want to know if there is any other way to achieve this as I need to have some more of such `foreach loops`, from which some contain very trivial code.

Comment: "One solution solution to this I found is having a separate function that contains the foreach loop and then calling the function for multiple arrays." That´s imho the best solution, as it reduces code-duplication. Pretty clear to future readers.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I currently used the same. Though I contain some more of similar foreach loops that may contain very less code, like incrementing a single property value by one or such. A separate function for every such operation loos like an overkill.

Comment: Extracting a seperate task into a function is never overkill, IMHO, as it makes your coce clearer and easier to understand. So even if you call that code only on a single location, it´s worth considering to refactor it into its own method. Asside from this you allways may consider to refactor everything that **is** similar into a common structure - e.g. a method, in order not repeat yourself.

Comment: yes this better and clean approach, please post your code as answer.

Comment: @Jasmeet As mentioned before a function is probably the best way to solve this. Also think about what is when another person have to maintain your code and have to search for a specific foreach-loop to change something. With a function its more clear what you are doing in the loop if you choose a "good" function name.

Comment: @it-person That's how currently I have my code. Will go with the same unless i don't find any other better way to do this.

Comment: also @Jasmeet, your example is slightly wrong, `DoOperations(array1);` should be `DoOperations({array1,array2});`

Answer (score 0):

```
Custom[] array1 = new Custom[10];
Custom[] array2 = new Custom[20];

var arr = arr1.Union(arr2).ToArray();

foreach(var v in array)
{
    // Do some operations
}
```

Comment: How will this work in case array contains value types ? I don't think it will automatically update any values in original arrays.

Comment: It will not work for any duplicate reference that implements IEquitable for that matter

Answer (score 0):

Please see below implementation

```
 public Func<custom[], custom[]> performOperation { get; set; }
 public custom[] iterateArray(custom[] arg)
        {
            foreach (var item in arg)
            {
                //Do operation
            }

            return arg;
        }
```

you can then assign the delegate to iterateArray method and invoke it please see below

```
    performOperation = iterateArray;
    performOperation(new custom[]{});
```

In this way you can invoke the delegate for multiple arrays of same type and if the operation logic is to change for any array you can then implement a method which abides by the delegate signature and assign it to the delegate.

Comment: This just creates an extra delegate that is used to invoke the function I need to call. I would rather prefer to call my function instead of introducing a new delegate to do the same.